# How do I find out what's linked to my Excel Worksheet?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I've got an Excel 2007 worksheet that I inherited, and each time it opens, I get the dialog box asking if I would like to update values from an outside, linked worksheet. I'm trying to track down if I should be saying yes or no; as I'm not familiar with the linked spreadsheet, nor what types of data it creates, nor if it's even in use and updated regularly.

Is there a way I can get a list of worksheets, paths, and linked cells so I can trace the formulae and see which links can be severed?

d

Answer (score 9, accepted):

These directions are for Excel 2010 (but if memory serves, Excel 2007 ribbon is the same in this area).

1. Go to Data Tab.
2. Choose Connections, this will open the Workbook Connections dialog.
3. In Workbook Connections dialog box it will list all of your connections.
4. Select the Connection in question and then click in the area below to see where it's used.

From there you'll also be able to check properties, add or delete connections.  It's a pretty handy place to visit if your worksheet has external data connected.

Answer (score 5):

One possible way is to use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>`</kbd> (the backwards apostrophe on the ~ key).  This will show all formulas in the cells, instead of just in the formula bar.  Plain data will remain untouched, but any formulas that update remotely should be pretty obvious.  Press the key sequence again to toggle back to normal viewing.

Answer (score 1):

In Excel from Office 365 you can click on Data tab and then on "Queries & Connections", it will show the connections you're using on your current workbook.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the Data tab, click on Edit Links and you should see a list of source files in which your file is pulling data from (or linked from).