# Find all Excel files linked

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

I have an Excel file that is the source of data for several other Excel files (they are linked to this one). Is there a way to find a list of all of those files?

To explain another way, [this post](https://superuser.com/questions/438323/how-do-i-find-out-whats-linked-to-my-excel-worksheet) addresses how to find all link *source* files. I'm trying to find all link *destination* files.

Comment: What version of Excel?

Comment: I'm using Excel 2010

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer:

**No!**

Long(er) answer:

No, if your current Excel file is the source of data for several other Excel files, so the linking information is saved ONLY in these files and NOT in your current file.